# Use VS2013 to browse localdb

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, ef-code-first, localdb

I am trying to follow along with this article ([EF Code First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591621)) and whilst the code runs and the output is what I expect, I can't browse to my `LocalDb` from within VS2013. I see my SQL Server 2012 developer instance but not my `LocalDb`. I can't find my `.mdf` file either.

The post says I should see the database in SQL Server Object Explorer, but I can't, and it doesn't seem obvious how to add it. I know I have SQL Server 2012 installed, and some of my project require it, but to get the most from the article I'd like to be able to follow along exactly.

Any ideas how I can see my project database file from VS2013?

Jason.

Comment: Is there an .mdf file (along with a .ldf file) located in the App_Data folder of your project (after enabling 'Show all files' in your solution or by browsing to the folder) ? What's in the ConnectionStrings section of your project's Web.config file ?

Comment: There is no App_Data folder in the demo console app I have created. There was also no explicit connectionstring. It appears to use the default one provided in the defaultConnectionFactory. It seems to all the world that the data is not being saved, but if I run the app a second time I see two records in the database, one for each time the program has been run.

Comment: Do you have SqlExpress installed? I believe it will default to SqlExpress over localDb if installed so worth checking.

Comment: I loaded it into VS2013 instead and everything now works perfectly. Thanks all.